# Is there a way to have a generic method on an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I want to access objects via an interface and have them return their enclosing class type.

```
interface IInterface<T> {
    T GetObject();
}

class MyClass : IInterface<MyClass> {
    MyClass GetObject { 
        return this; 
    }
}
```

This is my current implementation, but it requires I know the type before accessing the interface.

Is there a way to do it without needing to know what type I will get back?

Comment: How you plan to resolve which type will be returned if you don't know it in advance?

Comment: Can you show how you want to use something like this? This is probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Good points. It may be an XY problem, but it's a better solution than I was using before :) ended up using `System.Object GetObject()`

Comment: Maybe `interface IInterface { T GetObject<T>(); }` really unclear what you are trying to achieve